# Request Cookie is 0 even if it is send in requestheader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm building a web api and I have a method in my controller which gives the user a cookie. I can see it in the browser it is set, everything is fine.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("[controller]/cookie")]
public IActionResult Cookie()
{
    string cookieName = "av225461";
    string key = $"blahblah";

    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
    cookieName, key,
    new CookieOptions() { SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified, HttpOnly = true, Expires = 
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)/*, Secure = true*/ });
    return Ok("");
}
```

But I am not able to read it in my Get method, if I am sending a request to my controller. The Cookies.Count is 0. Even if the cookie is set in browser and inthe requestheader of Firefox.

```
 if (Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
 {
    //some code here
 }
```

With postman sometimes it worked, and sometimes not. Someone an idea?

Comment: Have you tried the `Add`? For example: `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(...)`.

Comment: @zaggler no, the cookie is set, I see it in the browser, but i cant read it

Comment: try it, what happens?

Comment: You did call `Cookies` object on `Request` which I think is different from `HttpContext.Request`. Try to get `HttpContext.Request.Cookies`.